# SQL Same Column in one row

Tags: sql-server

I have a lookup table that has a Name and an ID in it. Example:

```
ID                                                  NAME
-----------------------------------------------------------
5499EFC9-925C-4856-A8DC-ACDBB9D0035E             CANCELLED
D1E31B18-1A98-4E1A-90DA-E6A3684AD5B0                31PR
```

The first record indicates and order status. The next indicates a service type.

In a query from an orders table I do the following:

```
INNER JOIN order.id = lut.Statusid
```

This returns the 'cancelled' name from my lookup table. I also need the service type in the same row. This is connected in the order table by the orders.serviceid How would I go about doing this?

It Cancelled doesnt connect to 31PR.

Orders connects to both. Orders has 2 fields in it called Servicetypeid and orderstatusid. That is how those 2 connect to the order. I need to return both names in the same order row.

Comment: You'd have to define what you mean by "next".  GUID's are not usually increasing, and the order in which you insert rows has no guaranteed meaning

Comment: How do the two rows connect (how do you know that that the 'canceled' status is connected to the 31pr service type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of info left out, but here it goes:

```
SELECT orders.id, lut1.Name AS OrderStatus, lut2.Name AS ServiceType
FROM orders
    INNER JOIN lut lut1 ON  order.id = lut.Statusid
    INNER JOIN lut lut2 ON order.serviceid = lut.Statusid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think many will tell you that having two different pieces of data in the same column violates first normal form. There is a reason why having one lookup table to rule them all is a bad idea. However, you can do something like the following:

```
Select  ..
From order
    Join lut
        On lut.Id = order.StatusId
    Left Join lut As l2
        On l2.id = order.ServiceTypeId
```

If `order.ServiceTypeId` (or whatever the column is named) is not nullable, then you can use a Join (inner join) instead.